# Как внедрить в сайт сделанный на hugo форму обратной связи (Например https://formspree.io/)

Tags: site

Имеется сайт на hugo, используется шаблон Clean White ([https://github.com/zhaohuabing/hugo-theme-cleanwhite).

Не могу разобраться как в него можно внедрить форму обратной связи, например https://formspree.io/

Answer (score 0):

Решил добавлением файла form-contact.html в папку hugo-theme-cleanwhite\layouts\shortcodes с примерно таким содержимым:

```html
<form id="fs-frm" name="simple-contact-form" accept-charset="utf-8" action="https://formspree.io/YOUR_EMAIL_HERE" method="post">
  <fieldset id="fs-frm-inputs">
    <label for="full-name">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="full-name" placeholder="First and Last" required="">
    <label for="email-address">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" name="_replyto" id="email-address" placeholder="email@domain.tld" required="">
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea rows="5" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla nullam quis risus." required=""></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="_subject" id="email-subject" value="Contact Form Submission">
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

И созданием поста во вставкой:

```
{{< form-contact action="https://formspree.io/YOUR_EMAIL_HERE" >}}
```